# Start Tomcat in windows using java code

Tags: java

I want to start tomcat using java program .

I had started in linux using the below code

```
String command = "c:\program files\tomcat\bin\startup.sh";
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

It works fine.

I used the following code in windows

```
String command = "c:/program files/tomcat/bin/startup.bat";
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Its not working .

Do i want to configure any other property for windows.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: `c:\program files` in linux, and not working ?any exception ?

Comment: yes.could not find the file path specified

Comment: `Process` object has `getErrorStream()` method, try reading what it says.

Comment: file path is :C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\startup.bat
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to just embed Tomcat and start it programmatically?

Comment: yes.i dont want to embed Tomcat .i want to start it programmatically.

Comment: suggestion: move the tomcat directory to one that doesn't have spaces in path to it, like c:/tomcat/tomcat7.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to set correctly the environment variable:

- JAVA_HOME

Comment: Only JAVA_HOME , no need for setting CATALINA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

You code is illegal.
you need to use "\\" for backslash in Java.
then, set the environment variables, JAVA_HOME AND CATALINA_HOME.

Comment: Only JAVA_HOME , no need for setting CATALINA_HOME

Comment: I tried by setting the environmental variable of JAVA_HOME.But it does not work

Comment: what's the location of the tomcat server in the linux machine? have you use: 'set JAVA_HOME=<location>' and then run from the same terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.just use

```
 String command = "D:/server/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/bin/startup.bat";
 File file = new File("D:/server/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/bin");
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/C", "start" ,command, 
 "start"}, null, file);
 Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command , "start" ).start();
```

Its working fine. But one thing file path doesn't have any spaces.

Comment: dont need to set catalina home also.